# How to create a shortcut that points to a program inside the USB stick?

Tags: shortcuts

I'm having problems creating a shortcut that will open my .exe file inside my USB stick because the Drive Letter usually change when the USB is inserted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of a little Windows batch scripting, you can have a script look for your .exe file (or any file) from all drives (A: to Z:). If found, the executable is run.

In this example, we suppose the file to find and execute are both *aerozoom.exe* which is located in a subfolder *AeroZoom* (where the full path can be *A-Z:\AeroZoom\aerozoom.exe*).

Modify the second and third line to *AeroZoom\aerozoom.exe*, then save the text file as e.g. "this_is_a_shortcut.bat" which can be placed on desktop as a shortcut.

```
@echo off
set fileToSearch=AeroZoom\aerozoom.exe
set fileToExecute=AeroZoom\aerozoom.exe
for %%i in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    if exist "%%i:\%fileToSearch%" start "" "%%i:\%fileToExecute%"
)
```

In case there is a file of the same filename and path on other drives, The 'fileToSearch' can be modified to search for another file which is located only on your desired drive.

Comment: @ wandersick : Great answer, this one saves my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a drive letter permanently on the drive through disk management. For windows 7 I right click on "computer" and choose "manage", then choose "disk management". Find the plugged in usb drive in disk management and right click and choose "Change Drive letter and paths".

It's a simple dialogue from there to either add a path or change the current drive letter.

If you change it to something in the middle or towards the end of the alphabet it won't conflict with other drive letters on the system and should always be the same. Then your short  cut should always work

Comment: @ isimmons : My Drive is not visible in Windows Disk Management because it is an encrypted portion of the drive. Lets say that my USB stick is "DRIVE H:", then inside this drive itself, I will need to open an encrypted file, that will later produce another Drive Letter (virtual). How can I create a shortcut that points into that newly produce drive letter? Is there a work around on this?

Comment: It all depends on what sofware is mounting that encrypted portion. If the mount process can be automated perhaps you can make it always mount on drive `I` and point the shortcut to `I:\Path\To\App.exe`

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a shortcut within the drive that points to another file in the drive, simply use references like such:

/programs/files/more/Run.EXE

Just make sure the shortcut is in the folder before 'programs/files...'

You may actually have to use a batch file if you go this route.